# Project Lombok Installation. [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError]

Tags: java, eclipse, lombok

I am trying to install project Lombok from an executable jar for eclipse neon 3 . 
But I am Receiving: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError Java Heap Space,
I am Using Lombok-1.16.10 jar.
[outOfMemoryException image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sedGr.png)

Please suggest a solution.
Thanks

Comment: Probably allocate more memory to Eclipse or buy some RAM if you're at maximum already.

Comment: @y_nk If I may have sounded wrong, the problem is with the installation of project Lombok, not with eclipse and I have 8gb of RAM I don't think that will be maxed out with just one eclipse and few chrome Tabs at a particular instance.  but I tried that as well It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `java -Xmx1G -jar lombok.jar`, keep in mind that the latest version of lombok is 1.18.12